# DOMElement::setAttribute(): string is not in UTF-8

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

After I installed a symfony application via composer I get the following error on cache clear:

> DOMElement::setAttribute(): string is not in UTF-8

Did try to run the cache-clear with `-vvv` but don't see which file is failing. Any way to get a list of all xml files which are not utf-8.

Comment: This is probably more a Symfony than a Composer issue. Raise PHP error reporting so that you get more info whats going on during installation. Configuration is wrong and the Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Dumper/XmlDumper.php fails.